# Restricting access to Firebase Firestore and Storage

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase exclusively in my app - Auth, Firestore, Functions and Storage.

Within Firestore, my data is structured as below:

```
/users/<user_id>/<user_data>
/listings/<listing_id>/<listing_data>
```

`<listing_data>` contains a `user_id` field.

Within Storage, my data is structured as below:

```
/images/<user_id>/<image_id>/<images>
```

I have the following scenario:

- A user must only be able to access their listings
- A user must only be able to download their files
- A user can can share their name from their `<user_data>` with selected users
- A user can share selected images with selected users

I have no ideas how I can go about this.  At the moment, anyone can access anything if they're authenticated, so I guess the first step is to lock this down, and then some how assign rights?

I thought about adding an access list object, and then writing middleware to check this, but it doesn't feel like the correct way

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify the rules of firestore as:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
        // Restaurants:
        //   - Authenticated user can read
        //   - Authenticated user can create/update (for demo)
        //   - Validate updates
        //   - Deletes are not allowed
    match /restaurants/{restaurantId} {
      allow read, create: if request.auth.uid != null;
      allow update: if request.auth.uid != null
                    && request.resource.data.name == resource.data.name
      allow delete: if false;

      // Ratings:
      //   - Authenticated user can read
      //   - Authenticated user can create if userId matches
      //   - Deletes and updates are not allowed
      match /ratings/{ratingId} {
        allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;
        allow create: if request.auth.uid != null
                      && request.resource.data.userId == request.auth.uid;
        allow update, delete: if false;

        }
    }
  }
}
```

The root of my database is restaurants.You have to replace those parameters with that of yours.

Comment: Ah!  OK, I had begun to rule that out as I didn't realise you could match based on ID.  I'll have a play with this

Comment: OK, so I got this working in a way. I guess that I will have to add a list in document of user id's that are allowed to access the document.
What I'm not sure if this resolves though is the download URL for an image.  Is it possible to restrict the URL to being only called through my webapp (so someone can't share an image url)